# Development before domain name chosen

Tags: permalinks, pages

I have a new customer who hasn't chosen a domain name yet but I need to start development for him using a subdomain of my domain. I'm on Bluehost using add-on domains and subfolders. Is there a way to convert the permalinks in the content easily? Can they be changed with SQL once he's selected a domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Search and Replace](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin to fix the URLs once the new domain is chosen.

Likewise, plugins such as [BackupBuddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) (paid) or [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) (free) -- which are very useful for backup, possibly coupled with migration to another server or domain -- also perform this search-and-replace operation.